# Nest js server crashing on Heroku

Tags: heroku, nestjs

My nest js server is crashing constantly on Heroku. Is there any way to automatically start the crashed server .
Thanks

Comment: Heroku should auto-restart. The more important thing is why is it crashing? Can you share logs about that?

Comment: It was crashing because of a value that was undefined. I fixed the code but I still need to know why the server was not auto-starting.

Comment: You'd need to show the Heroku logs. After making your change did you push the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for a way to automatically start the application after the crash, yes there are and one of them is using [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) which is a popular one.

You can simply install it using `npm`:

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

Run your app using the command:

```
pm2 start "<application_startup_command>" --name <app_name>
```

With this in place, the application will automatically start after the crash.  PM2 is an awesome package. You get a lot of features like monitoring, startup script, and so on. I recommend reading the [documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/) for this.

**Note:** But this doesn't mean will solve your issue causing a crash but just tries to restart the server.